# Having trouble returning truncated copy of array

Tags: java, arrays, copy, return

I have created a method that is supposed to create a copy of an array of length up to the number of values stored in the original array. So if my original array is of length 10, and I only have 4 values contained in it, then my copy of that array should be of length 3. Here is my code:

```
       public int[] getArray(){
             int[] temp = new int[size];
             for(int i = 0; i<size; i++){
                temp[i] = a[i];
                //System.out.print(temp[i] + " ");
        }
        return temp;
     }
```

I used the print statement to make sure it copies the array and it does. It prints it out when I call this method in my main method. But when I comment out the print statement and use "return temp" it returns the memory location. How would I print the values in the copied array WITHOUT using the JCF or any built in methods? I must use a return statement and the name of the method must remain exactly the same for the specifications our teacher provided. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You mean your copy should be of length 4 to contain all the four elements?. Anyway what do you want? you want to print on the console the elements of the array?

Comment: Yes. My copy should only be big enough to hold the number of actual values, not including the empty indices. I got that part done. I just want to find a way to use "return" in the method getArray() and print the actual values in the main method by calling the method getArray() WITHOUT using any imports or JCF. Basically handwritten code from scratch. Mr Albert's answer below works correctly but I am trying to find out if it's possible to do it from scratch. I can only find answers similar to Mr. Alberts. Maybe it's not possible.

Comment: @Harold Look at the source code of `Arrays.toString(int[] a)`. This is (almost) _from scratch_. Though re-inventing proven wheels is a bad idea in general.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To output a whole array, not just its address, use `java.util.Arrays.toString()`.

```
System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(getArray()));
```

Comment: Would it be possible to rewrite your print statement so it does not use java.util.Arrays? Or is that not possible. I am unsure what exactly my professor wants and she doesn't respond very quickly to e-mails. So I've been trying to figure out how to do it without importing anything